# Stringr pattern to detect capitalized words

Tags: r, stringr

I am trying to write a function to detect capitalized words that are all capitalised

currently, code:

```
df <- data.frame(title = character(), id = numeric())%>%
        add_row(title= "THIS is an EXAMPLE where I DONT get the output i WAS hoping for", id = 6)

df <- df %>%
        mutate(sec_code_1 = unlist(str_extract_all(title," [A-Z]{3,5} ")[[1]][1]) 
               , sec_code_2 = unlist(str_extract_all(title," [A-Z]{3,5} ")[[1]][2]) 
               , sec_code_3 = unlist(str_extract_all(title," [A-Z]{3,5} ")[[1]][3]))
df
```

Where output is:

| title | id | sec_code_1 | sec_code_2 | sec_code_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| THIS is an EXAMPLE where I DONT get the output i WAS hoping for | 6 | DONT | WAS |  |

The first 3-5 letter capitalized word is "THIS", second should skip example (>5) and be "DONT", third example should be "WAS".
ie:

| title | id | sec_code_1 | sec_code_2 | sec_code_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| THIS is an EXAMPLE where I DONT get the output i WAS hoping for | 6 | THIS | DONT | WANT |

does anyone know where Im going wrong? specifically how I can denote "space or beginning of string" or "space or end of string" logically using stringr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the code with your regex you'll realise `'THIS'` is not included in the output at all.

```
str_extract_all(df$title," [A-Z]{3,5} ")[[1]]
#[1] " DONT " " WAS "
```

This is because you are extracting words with leading and lagging whitespace. `'THIS'` does not have lagging whitespace because it is start of the sentence, hence it does not satisfy the regex pattern. You can use word boundaries (`\\b`) instead.

```
str_extract_all(df$title,"\\b[A-Z]{3,5}\\b")[[1]]
#[1] "THIS" "DONT" "WAS"
```

Your code would work if you use the above pattern in it.

Or you could also use :

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(code = str_extract_all(title,"\\b[A-Z]{3,5}\\b")) %>%
  unnest_wider(code) %>%
  rename_with(~paste0('sec_code_', seq_along(.)), starts_with('..'))

# title                                     id sec_code_1 sec_code_2 sec_code_3
#  <chr>                                  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
#1 THIS is an EXAMPLE where I DONT get t…     6 THIS       DONT       WAS
```

Comment: legend, this is exactly what I was looking for. didnt know about word boundaries