# unlisted string operation to create new variables is only performing for first row?

Tags: r, stringr

I've written code to extract the first three suspected  security codes from comment data:

```
flag_stock_codes <- function(df) {

        # NYSE has 3 digit codes, NASDAQ has 2-5. 
        # there arent a lot of 2 digit codes though so we will use 3-5 to avoid excess false positives       
       df <- df %>%
        mutate(sec_code_1 = unlist(str_extract_all(title,"\\b[A-Z]{3,5}+\\b")[[1]][1]) 
               , sec_code_2 = unlist(str_extract_all(title,"\\b[A-Z]{3,5}+\\b")[[1]][2]) 
               , sec_code_3 = unlist(str_extract_all(title,"\\b[A-Z]{3,5}+\\b")[[1]][3]))
       df
}


# test 1
test %>% filter(id %in% c("l98qhb","l98ppp")) %>% flag_stock_codes()
```

Output:

```
      id                                                    title score              author author_flair_text removed_by
1 l98qhb IF NOK HITS $500/SHARE, I'LL TATTOO DIAMONDS ON MY HANDS     1 Money_trees_planted                    moderator
2 l98ppp                                      AMC GME TO THE MARS     1         tehspiekguy                    moderator
  total_awards_received awarders created_utc
1                     0       []  1612084105
2                     0       []  1612084011
                                                                                                full_link num_comments over_18
1 https://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/l98qhb/if_nok_hits_500share_ill_tattoo_diamonds_on_my/            0   False
2                            https://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/l98ppp/amc_gme_to_the_mars/            0   False
  sec_code_1 sec_code_2 sec_code_3
1        NOK       HITS      SHARE
2        NOK       HITS      SHARE
```

However I notice my logic is only extracting the first row, and filling all others with this value. I want it to be a row by row operation for each comment:

ie last three columns:

| sec_code_1 | sec_code_2 | sec_code_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NOK | HITS | SHARE |
| AMC | GME | THE |

Does anyone know how I can modify my logic to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is extracting only first row because you are telling it to do that when you specify `[[1]]` in the code. You can use `map_chr` with `pluck`.

```
library(tidyverse)

flag_stock_codes <- function(df) {
  
  df %>%
    mutate(sec_code_1 = map_chr(str_extract_all(title,"\\b[A-Z]{3,5}+\\b"), pluck, 1), 
           sec_code_2 = map_chr(str_extract_all(title,"\\b[A-Z]{3,5}+\\b"), pluck, 2), 
           sec_code_3 = map_chr(str_extract_all(title,"\\b[A-Z]{3,5}+\\b"), pluck, 3))
  
}

test %>% filter(id %in% c("l98qhb","l98ppp")) %>% flag_stock_codes()
```

And again if you would have followed [my answer on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66235343/3962914) then you wouldn't get this issue in the first place.

```
flag_stock_codes <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    mutate(code = str_extract_all(title,"\\b[A-Z]{3,5}\\b")) %>%
    unnest_wider(code) %>%
    rename_with(~paste0('sec_code_', seq_along(.)), starts_with('..'))
}

test %>%
  filter(id %in% c("l98qhb","l98ppp"))
  flag_stock_codes()
```